# Change the way the program prompts the user for input

Tags: java, list, sorting

This program prompts the user to enter how many numbers are in their list, then prompts the user for the actual numbers in the list. It then decides if the numbers in the list are already sorted. It works completely fine, but I want the program to prompt the user for the amount of numbers in the list AND the list at once instead of prompting the user for the number and then prompting the user however as many times as the number that the user previously input. Sorry that's so long, here's an example of the output vs. what I'm looking:

**Current output:**

```
Enter a number for the length of the list: 5

Enter list: 
1

Enter list: 
3

Enter list: 
2

Enter list: 
4

Enter list: 
5

The list is not sorted.
```

**What I'm trying to go for:**

```
Enter a number for the length of the list: 5 1 3 2 4 5

The list is not sorted.
```

**Code:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question7_19 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a number for the length of the list: ");
        int listLength = input.nextInt();
        int[] number = new int[listLength];

        for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter list: ");
            number[i] = input.nextInt();
        }

        if (isSorted(number)) {
            System.out.println("The list is sorted.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The list is not sorted.");
        }
    }

    public static boolean isSorted(int[] list) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length - 1; i++) {
            if (list[i] > list[i + 1]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use StringTokenizer to tokenize the input.  This will allow the array numbers to be entered on one line.  This also determines the size of the array based on the amount of tokens provided by the user.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter a numbers: ");
    String input = scanner.nextLine();

    StringTokenizer s = new StringTokenizer(input);

    int[] number = new int[s.countTokens()];

    int index = 0;
    while(s.hasMoreTokens()){
        String item = s.nextToken();
        try{
            number[index] = Integer.parseInt(item);
            index++;
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    if (isSorted(number)) {
        System.out.println("The list is sorted.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("The list is not sorted.");
    }

    scanner.close();
}

public static boolean isSorted(int[] list) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length - 1; i++) {
        if (list[i] > list[i + 1]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Edit: You can also split the string and loop through the elements of the array returned.

```
String[] splitInput = input.split(" ");

int[] number = new int[splitInput.length];

for(int i = 0 ; i < splitInput.length ; i++){
    String item = splitInput[i];
    try{
        number[i] = Integer.parseInt(item);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        i--;
    }
}
```

Comment: We also haven't learned about this yet, but thank you so much for trying to help! I really appreciate it

Comment: You could use this as an opportunity to learn these two methods and expand your knowledge base. :) Good luck!